# Composition factors above a subnormal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ has a composition series and let $H$ be a subnormal subgroup of $G$.
Then $H$ is a term of a composition series of $G$.
I know that the number of terms above $H$ in any composition series of $G$ is unique.
Let $$1=G_0\leq ... \leq G_n =H \leq G_{n+1}\leq \dots \leq G_k=G-(1)$$
and $$1=L_0\leq ... \leq L_n =H \leq L_{n+1}\leq \dots \leq L_k=G - (2)$$
I want to show that there is a bijection $\alpha$ between $\{G_{n+1}/G_n,\dots,G_k/G_{k-1}\}$ and $\{L_{n+1}/L_n,\dots,L_k/L_{k-1}\}$ such that $$G_i/G_{i-1}\cong L_{\alpha(i)}/L_{\alpha(i)-1}$$
Here I can obtain another composition series $$1=L_0\leq ... \leq L_n  =H \leq G_{n+1}\leq \dots \leq G_k=G - (3)$$
By Jordan Holder Theorem, (2) and (3) are equivalent.
Hence there is a bijection between the composition factors of (2) and (3).
However I still can't get the result because it might happen that $$G_i/G_{i-1}\cong L_{j}/L_{j-1}$$
where $i\in \{n+1,\dots,k\}$ and $j\in \{1,\dots,n\}$

Comment: But to answer your question, the factors below $H$ in (2) clearly correspond (via isomorphism) to those below $H$ in (3),  so those above $H$ in (2) must correspond to those above $H$ in (3).

Comment: @DerekHolt In the beginning I have made the assumption that $G$ has a composition series. Also although there is a bijection $\phi$ between the composition factors of (2) and (3),but in my opinion I think that it might happen the case where some factor above $H$ in (2) corresponds to factor below $H$ in (3). In other words, $\phi$ does not necessarily induce a bijection on the composition factors below $H$ in (2) and (3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of the isomorphism classes of a composition series as being a multiset, recording the number of times each composition factor occurs. For example, this multiset for $S_5 \times C_2$ is $\{ (C_2,2), (A_5,1) \}$. The Jordan-Hölder Theorem says that these multisets arising from two different composition factors of the same group are equal.

In your situation, let $A$ be the multiset of composition factors of $G$. Then the composition factors of $H$ form a submultiset $B$ of $A$, and the factors lying above $H$ form the multiset $B \setminus A$, which must be the same for both series.

For example if $A = \{ (C_2,3), (C_5,2), (A_5,2), (A_7,4) \}$ and $B = \{ (C_2,2), (A_5,2), (A_7,2) \}$, then the factors above $H$ must be $\{ (C_2,1), (C_5,2), (A_7,2) \}$.